# What happens to signal lower than input offset voltage

Tags: amplifier

If a signal is lower than the input offset volatge like this 10uV (microvolt) signal with amplifier having an input offset voltage of 20uV (microvolt), will it cause non-linearities of the amplitude like the following? If not, How does signal lower than input offset voltage behave?

[image]

Comment: What is your workflow and software use to get to this point with Audacity? Is there any real hardware in the chain? Or is everything a series of simulators, generators and other software getting to this point? What are those little dots on the 50 Hz? Sample points?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the output remains in the linear range the signal will be amplified just fine (although with an offset at the output).

Comment: So what could have caused the amplitudes in the picture not to be uniform?

Comment: @Jtl Resolution. Aliasing. And limitations on the numerical nature of the simulation.

Comment: What? The Netech EEG simulator can output clear 10 microVolt. so it is supposed to produce output with uniform amplitudes. But in the circuit, the amplitudes are not uniform? Could it just be caused by interference current only?